# How to remove the com.apple.security.get-task-allow entitlement from the release build?

Tags: xcode, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I'm building my app with Xcode using `Release` configuration for production:

[image]

But then when I check the resulting binary for entitlements:

```
codesign -d --entitlements - --xml /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LABService-emdoarcsbzcuepbrkkkpbcckcaqx/Build/Products/Release/MyAppName
```

I'm getting:

```
Executable=/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LABService-emdoarcsbzcuepbrkkkpbcckcaqx/Build/Products/Release/MyAppName
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "https://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
      <key>com.apple.security.get-task-allow</key>
      <true/>
   </dict>
</plist>
```

How do I remove the `com.apple.security.get-task-allow` entitlement from the release build (but keep it for the debug config build)?

Answer (score 0):

OK, answering my own question. The `com.apple.security.get-task-allow` entitlement will be automatically removed when you code-sign the binary. I'm not sure if it will be done with the `codesign` command line tool, but the [Xcode does it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues?language=objc#3087731) from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode automatically adds the Get Task Allow entitlement to apps that you build for debugging, while removing the entitlement before App Store submission. This enables Xcode itself to attach to and debug your app during development.